# Python: Access to other Classes Objects

Tags: python, class

I have a question regarding the classes in python3. In my programm i have a "main" class that is getting started first and sets some parameters that are needed for the other parts of the programm. But now my other classes need some objects of the main class. How can i use the objects of the main class without initialising the main class everytime the subclass needs the object ? I looked into python inheritance but maybe i didnt understand it correctly

```
class Chunk(main.Main):
    def __init__(self,pos_in_world_x,pos_in_world_y):
        #self.chunksize =  settings.blocks_per_chunk
        self.prog = main.Main.prog
        self.ctx = main.Main.ctx
```

this is my code for the subclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use class variables:

```
class Main():
    prog = 1
    ctx = 2
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Chunk(Main):
    def __init__(self, pos_in_world_x, pos_in_world_y):
        self.prog = Main.prog
        self.ctx = Main.ctx

a = Chunk(3, 4)
print(a.prog)  # 1
print(a.ctx)   # 2
```

If you can't change `Main` to move your definitions outside `__init__`, then what you're asking for is impossible. If your variable is defined in `__init__`, you can't access it before calling `__init__`, i.e. initialising the class. You can't get round this.

Answer (score 0):

You need a super `__init__` call in your subclass and if you have that you only need to do:

```
class Chunk(main.Main):
    def __init__(self,pos_in_world_x,pos_in_world_y):
        super().__init__()
        #self.chunksize =  settings.blocks_per_chunk
```

Both of the assignments are done by Main's `__init__`.

But I think that Chunk has not an **is-a** but rather a **has-a** relation with Main so Main should actually be an argument rather than a super class:

```
class Chunk(object):
    def __init__(self, main, pos_in_world_x,pos_in_world_y):
        #self.chunksize =  settings.blocks_per_chunk
        self.prog = main.prog
        self.ctx = main.ctx
```

Any one that creates a Chunk must pass a Main instance.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually difficult to hide information in Python, so here are a few options which don't require inheritance (see jpp's answer for the inheritance option). In general, the code is easier to understand when you pass information explicitly (option 1 below, or inheritance), but there may be cases where you'd prefer the other options.

**Option 1**: The needed info can simply be passed as additional arguments to `Chunk`'s `__init__` (either by passing the `prog` and `ctx` values themselves, or by passing the `Main` class or its instance - depending on whether the needed info is stored as class or instance variables). Here's an example of passing `Main` as an argument:

```
class Main():
    prog = 1
    ctx = 2
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Chunk():
    def __init__(self, pos_in_world_x, pos_in_world_y, M):
        #self.chunksize =  settings.blocks_per_chunk
        self.prog = M.prog
        self.ctx = M.ctx

c = Chunk(3, 4, Main)
print(c.prog)  # 1
print(c.ctx)   # 2
```

**Option 2**: `Chunk` can access `Main`'s class variables directly:

```
class Main():
    prog = 1
    ctx = 2
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Chunk():
    def __init__(self, pos_in_world_x, pos_in_world_y):
        #self.chunksize =  settings.blocks_per_chunk
        self.prog = Main.prog
        self.ctx = Main.ctx

c = Chunk(3, 4)
print(c.prog)  # 1
print(c.ctx)   # 2
```

**Option 3**: `Chunk` can access the instance variables of the `Main` instance directly (`Main` needs to be instantiated before `Chunk` is instantiated):

```
class Main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.prog = 1
        self.ctx = 2

class Chunk():
    def __init__(self, pos_in_world_x, pos_in_world_y):
        #self.chunksize =  settings.blocks_per_chunk
        self.prog = m.prog
        self.ctx = m.ctx

m = Main()
c = Chunk(3, 4)
print(c.prog)  # 1
print(c.ctx)   # 2
```